# Create clusters in R

Tags: r, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have a df that looks like:

```
selection.body selection.hair selection.eyes selection.breasts selection.butt selection.skin         
normal         blonde          other             large         medium         tanned
normal         blonde          other                xl         medium         tanned
normal         blonde          other             large         medium         tanned
chubby         blonde           blue                xl          large         tanned
slim           blonde          other            medium          small          white
```

Let's imagine this dataset as the answer to a survey:

- each row represents the choice of a single responder, selecting his preference from a closed set of preferences.

What I did already is checking the frequencies of each choice but I want to move forward with that.

My goal is to:

- identify the most common combinations of choices.
- group the users on the basis of this combination.
- the correlations between the choices

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Try `data.table`. Following syntax should be enough to answer first two questions: `dt[,.(Count = .N),.(col1, col2... etc)]`. For third question try `?cor` from base and `corrplot` package.

Comment: It looks to me you just hand over your tasks to others!

Comment: I didnt ask for any code. I'm just asking for brainstorming and have hints to start. It looks to me you have a lot of time on your hands tho

Answer (score 0):

Finding the most common combinations isn't clustering, but frequent itemset mining.

Have you tried apriori?

Comment: What I came up with is to find a correlation between multiple categorical variables, loglinear model with MASS and then a mosaic plot following: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcdExtra/vignettes/vcd-tutorial.pdf. Very useful. But indeed it isn't clustering. What's apriori about?